# How to make all values in a row after a specific value appears, NA in R

Tags: r, dataframe, recode

I have data in R that looks like this:

```
T1 <- c(0,0,0,0,0)
T2 <- c(1,0,0,0,0)
T3 <- c(0,1,0,0,0)
T4 <- c(1,1,0,NA,1)
T5 <- c(0,1,0,NA,0)
df <- data.frame(T1,T2,T3,T4,T5)

  T1 T2 T3 T4 T5
1  0  1  0  1  0
2  0  0  1  1  1
3  0  0  0  0  0
4  0  0  0 NA NA
5  0  0  0  1  0
```

What I am hoping to do is to turn every value after the 1st "1" appears into NA. So it would look something like this:

```
  T1 T2 T3 T4 T5
1  0  1 NA NA NA
2  0  0  1 NA NA
3  0  0  0  0  0
4  0  0  0 NA NA
5  0  0  0  1 NA
```

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `apply` from base R
Get the first 1 with `which.max`

`first1 = which.max(x == 1)`

Generate an integer that can be sequenced and subset the values that are not within the sequence.
`mySeq <-ifelse(first1 == 1, length(x), first1)`

Subsetted values are given NA

`x[-seq(mySeq)] <- NA`

return values

```
df[] <- t(apply(df, 1, \(x) {
  first1 = which.max(x == 1)
  mySeq <-ifelse(first1 == 1, length(x), first1)
  x[-seq(mySeq)] <- NA
  x
  }))
```

```
  T1 T2 T3 T4 T5
1  0  1 NA NA NA
2  0  0  1 NA NA
3  0  0  0  0  0
4  0  0  0 NA NA
5  0  0  0  1 NA
```

Comment: No problem at all :)

Answer (score 4):

We could use `rowCumsums` to create a logical vector and then do the assign

```
library(matrixStats)
df[rowCumsums(rowCumsums(df == 1)) > 1] <- NA
```

-output

```
> df
  T1 T2 T3 T4 T5
1  0  1 NA NA NA
2  0  0  1 NA NA
3  0  0  0  0  0
4  0  0  0 NA NA
5  0  0  0  1 NA
```

Comment: A *base* variant: `df[t(apply(df==1, 1, \(x) cumsum(cumsum(x)) > 1))]  <- NA`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach with first pivoting to long format:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  group_by(group =as.integer(gl(n(),max(parse_number(name)),n()))) %>% 
  mutate(value1 = ifelse(1:n() > which(value == 1)[1], NA, value),
         y = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(value = ifelse(y == 0, value, value1), .keep="unused") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
```

```
  group    T1    T2    T3    T4    T5
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0     1    NA    NA    NA
2     2     0     0     1    NA    NA
3     3     0     0     0     0     0
4     4     0     0     0    NA    NA
5     5     0     0     0     1    NA
```